# My website is showing today's date instead of published date since db migration to a new wordpress

Tags: posts, database, migration, date, content

I exported my database and content to a new Wordpress. Everything works fine, except that every post is showing under today's date, instead of the published date like it should be (the actual published date is the good one in the dashboard though).

It was working correctly in my last Wordpress (5.0.11). The new one is 5.6.1. Here's the PHP related to the date in my theme :

```
<span class="post-date">
    <?php
    $date = date_i18n( get_option( 'date_format' ), strtotime( get_the_date( 'r' ) ) );
    printf( esc_html_x( 'Publié le %s', 'Publié le DATE', 'chosen' ), $date );
    ?>
</span>
```

Any idea what happened?

Comment: Did the dates get imported correctly in the database? If you look in the wp_posts table do you see the correct dates in post_date / post_date_gmt and post_modified / post_modified_gmt?

Comment: How did you perform the import/export?